Do multiple commands in one line with Autohotkey
Instead of a shortcut in multiple lines finishing by Return:
#a::
    RunWait calc.exe
    Sleep 500
    Send ^v
    Return

Is there a way to do this in one line?
This does not work:
#m:: RunWait calc.exe && Sleep 500 && Send ^v


The multiline version is better readable, so why do you want to put everything on 1 line ?  (see: "Line breaks generally act as a statement separator, terminating the previous command or expression" on this page)

Ok @Luuk, this is just a toy example here. In general I'd like to know if there is a multiple-statement-per-line syntax in Autohotkey syntax/grammar.

No.

Line breaks are meaningful: Line breaks generally act as a statement separator, terminating the previous function call or other statement. (A statement is simply the smallest standalone element of the language that expresses some action to be carried out.)

See documentation.
Use functions if you want to shorten some hotkey blocks:
#a::DoStuff

DoStuff()
{
  RunWait calc.exe
  Sleep 500
  Send ^v
  Return
}

The Return statement can be omitted, BTW.

Some lines can be combined into a single line using , (comma).
Source AHK v1

Comma (multi-statement) [v1.0.46+]
Commas may be used to write multiple sub-expressions on a single line. This is most commonly used to group together multiple assignments or function calls.
For example: x:=1, y+=2, ++index, MyFunc(). Such statements are executed in order from left to right.

Source AHK v2

Comma (multi-statement)
Commas may be used to write multiple sub-expressions on a single line. This is most commonly used to group together multiple assignments or function calls.
For example: x:=1, y+=2, ++index, MyFunc(). Such statements are executed in order from left to right.

Not sure if this helps with your example. You might have to experiment.
Ask AHK experts for help at their forum.
